# Where is located the source code of IWindowManager.java?

Tags: android, android-source

Something strange I can't understand, under the source code of android I can not find the file IWindowManager.java ? Where is it located ? normally must be in `import android.view.IWindowManager`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IWindowManager` is autogenerated from an AIDL file located [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/IWindowManager.aidl) and in order to see the Java source you must build the Android source code first. There's no `IWindowManager.java` currently checked in.

If you don't want to build Android itself but still want to see an example of what the Java source looks like then there's a few websites like grepcode.com that can show you that (see: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/IWindowManager.java#IWindowManager).

Answer (score 0):

It's here:
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/src/core/java/android/view/IWindowManager.java